# Jenkins shows log4j complaining with: log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins, log4j

Can someone please help me figure out why Jenkins keeps complaining about log4j when it works from the IDE? I'm familiar with the error and what the fix for it is. I have a log4j.properties file in my src folder.  When I run my tests from the IDE, I don't see this error. Only from Jenkins. Any help would be appreciated.

THIS IS NOT THE SAME QUESTION AS THE ONES I'M BEING LINKED TO! READ THE QUESTION PLEASE!  THIS IS HAPPENING IN JENKINS, NOT IN THE IDE.

Thanks

**Stack:**

```
Started by user anonymous
Building in workspace C:\Users\userm4\.jenkins\jobs\Company Smoke Test\workspace
[Selenium Main] $ cmd.exe /C '"C:\apache-ant-1.9.4\bin\ant.bat -file TestNG run makexsltreports && exit %%ERRORLEVEL%%"'
Buildfile: E:\Selenium Main\TestNG\build.xml

setClassPath:

init:

clean:
   [delete] Deleting directory E:\Selenium Main\TestNG\build

compile:
     [echo] making directory...
    [mkdir] Created dir: E:\Selenium Main\TestNG\build
     [echo] classpath------: E:\Selenium Main\TestNG\lib\SaxonLiaison.jar:E:\Selenium Main\TestNG\lib\jtds-1.3.1.jar:E:\Selenium Main\TestNG\lib\junit-4.11.jar:E:\Selenium Main\TestNG\lib\log4j-1.2.17.jar:E:\Selenium Main\TestNG\lib\mysql-connector-java-5.1.34.jar:E:\Selenium Main\TestNG\lib\saxon-8.7.jar:E:\Selenium Main\TestNG\lib\selenium-java-2.44.0.jar:E:\Selenium Main\TestNG\lib\selenium-server-standalone-2.44.0.jar:E:\Selenium Main\TestNG\lib\testng-6.8.8.jar
     [echo] compiling...
    [javac] E:\Selenium Main\TestNG\build.xml:66: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
    [javac] Compiling 52 source files to E:\Selenium Main\TestNG\build

run:
   [testng] [TestNG] Running:
   [testng]   E:\Selenium Main\TestNG\testng.xml
   [testng] 
   [testng] log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies).
   [testng] log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
   [testng] log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

...

Comment: It is a duplicate, the problem is not in the IDE or Jenkins, it is in your build/code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try move log4j.properties to `WEB-INF/classes` in your build or add `-Dlog4j.configuration=theconfig` on your job command.

Comment: I tried this in Eclipse and it still gives me the error.

Comment: I ended up fixing this by dumping Ant and going with Maven 3. I then placed my log4j.properties into my resource folder.